# PowerShell lots of empty lines

Tags: powershell

Im completly new to Stackoverflow an I will try my best making this right. So I appriciate Tips!

My Problem: I'm starting to use PowerShell a little bit, an I have a lot of empy lines in the log that I want to output, where there shouldnt be any.
I'm just trying to get the LastWriteTime and the Name of the newest file. [MyCode and Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO9Pr.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The same thing everyone does wrong. Use `select-object -expandproperty Name` instead of `fl name`.

Comment: Code shouldn't be an image. Code should also be here, unless unreasonably long. Get rid of the intro line - we all know that by the reputation score. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there - you just need to select the specific properties you want when using the `select` cmdlet:

```
gci -rec *.txt | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 LastWriteTime,Name
```